# I want a simulation program for a multiprocessor system

Tags: open-source, programming, simulation, multi-threading

I am looking for a simulation program that will help me link a number of processors and apply some algorithms to them.
I need this program for a research I am doing

Comment: We will need much for information than that. Please , help us to help you by giving some detail.Thanks